# Errors of camera libraries in React Native

Tags: react-native, runtime-error, react-native-vision-camera

When I install react-native-vision-camera and react-native-camera-kit libraries in my application. I'm getting the build failed error and my app is not working. There is no problem with libraries other than these.

[image]

Comment: Please checkout "Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Looks like some additional configs need to be made. Kindly check the complete installation guide of the packages.